# Define pointer variable using auto

Tags: c++, pointers, auto

I want to declare a pointer variable (for the sake of this question lets assume of type `int`) and initialize it by `nullptr`, e.g.

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
```

For consistency purposes I want to deduce its type using `auto`, but the following looks cumbersome

```
auto* ptr = static_cast<int*>(nullptr); // compiles
```

Is there a cleaner way? Something along the lines of

```
auto* ptr = int*{nullptr}; // doesn't compile
```

Comment: `auto ptr = (int*)nullptr;` - but why you would want to do this escapes me.

Comment: You could hide the cumbersome conversion in a variable template, e.g.: `template<typename T> constexpr auto null_pointer = static_cast<T*>(nullptr);` and then `auto ptr = null_pointer<int>;` or something along these lines. But as also mentioned by other comments, it is going to be hard to keep with _always auto_ consistently anyway.

Comment: *"For consistency purposes"* - The famous guideline is "**almost** always auto" for a reason. I'm personally not a fan of taking consistency to the extreme. As you find out, it can keep you *away* from the more readable option.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica AAA and AAAA? :P